# Is Beagalltach mentioned in the Iron Druid Chronicles?

Tags: iron-druid, moralltach, beagalltach

I was curious about the sword known as Beagalltach, also known as Little Fury.  In *the Iron Druid Chronicles* book series, Atticus is shown as having Moralltach, but is there any mention of Beagalltach in any of the books in the series?

Answer (score 2):

I just went through all the pronunciation guides/glossaries Hearne includes in the books, and there's no mention of Beagalltach; nor can I remember reading about it.

The other major sword he writes about, that Atticus uses is Fragarach.

Comment: Yeah your wrong about that... He has Moralltach after defeating Aengus Og... Moralltach is the another magical sword currently possessed by Atticus O'Sullivan, the last Druid and protagonist of The Iron Druid Chronicles. He acquired possession of Moralltach in Hounded by defeating Aenghus Óg. It has the power to kill anything with one simple cut - although the death does come slowly over a brief period of time.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wrote.  I never said he didn't use Moralltach, I wrote "the other major sword" is Fragarach.  There's no mention of Beagalltach as far as I can remember.  To clarify, Atticus has had in his possession both Moralltach and Fragarach at one point or another.  So I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

I've read the Iron Druid series several times. I can assure you that the only swords named/used in the books were Moralltach and Fragarach.